# Powerquery - rows to columns

Tags: powerquery

I have sample data like below and I am trying to use PowerQuery to transpose it into different shape.

Here is my data:

```
Identifier    Id
Account Type  1
Account Type  2
Account Type  3
```

Here is what I need:

```
Identifier    Column.1 Column.2 Column.3
Account Type         1        2        3
```

I tried all combinations of Transpose + Unpivot but nothing worked.

Comment: did any of the answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Method1: If there will only be one identifier type, then Add column... index column ....  Then click select the index column and use transform...pivot column... and select ID as the values column, advanced options Don't Aggregate

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Id")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Method2: If you plan to have different identifiers, then you need something a bit more complex.  This adds the index within each group. Then you can pivot

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Identifier"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Id", "Index"}, {"Id", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Id", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Group by Identifier; then do a custom Text Aggregation which you can split into columns:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table25"]}[Content],

//type the ID column as text for later purposes
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Identifier", type text}, {"Id", type text}}),

//group by Identifier, then custom Text aggregation with delimiter
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Identifier"}, {
        {"Id",each Text.Combine([Id],";")}}),

//split the column by the delimiter, and set the data types
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Id", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Id.1", "Id.2", "Id.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Id.1", Int64.Type}, {"Id.2", Int64.Type}, {"Id.3", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]